# angular-translate static files won't load properly sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate-loader-static-files and it works like a charm. Well... almost.
For some reason my json files won't load properly everytime.

I have 2 json files locale-en.json and locale-fr.json

Loaded this way :

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader {
  prefix: 'locales/locale-'
  suffix: '.json'
}

$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage 'fr'
```

Most of the time everything works just fine but sometimes the files aren't loaded, in the network console the locale-xx.json response is index.html

I think the problem comes from modifying the json files, then refreshing the page. Restarting Chrome sometimes fixes this problem, until it comes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding a / before 'locales/locale-'

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader {
  prefix: '/locales/locale-'
  suffix: '.json'
}
```

What happened is that it tried to load locales/local-xx.json from the current url.

For example if I was on the route

> localhost:8080/users

the request was

> localhost:8080/users/locales/locale-xx.json

instead of

> localhost:8080/locales/locale-xx.json